# date of 7 days after on a input tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

How can I give a value to a `<input>` tag to be set always for one week after?

I have today's date which is

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('v_doc_fechaemision').value = (new Date()).format("yy/m/dd");
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="v_doc_fechaemision" name="v_doc_fechaemision">
```

What would it be if I were to set this for +7 days?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want this in PHP or in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
var days = 7;
var date = new Date();
var res = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
alert(res);
```

You can also try this

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

var dateMsg = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
alert(dateMsg);
```

Comment: Thank you so which id should i use in my input to call this function?

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php echo strtotime("+1 week")?>
```

or

```
<?php echo strtotime("+7 days")?>
```

So for your code, you would do:

```
<input type="hidden" id="v_doc_fechaemision" name="v_doc_fechaemision" value="<?php echo strtotime("+1 week"); ?>">
```

If You need `v_doc_fechaemision` to be 7 days ahead of a value in another input, you will need to write some AJAX to update the value.

Comment: by just adding the <?php echo strtotime("+7 days")?> on the input tag as a value will work? Do i need any PHP function to read this strtotime? Than kyou